# Pegar valor máximo da tabela (JPA) com Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Tenho um método na minha classe DAO que retorna uma lista geral da tabela:

```
public List<ObjetoRisco> findAll() {
    return manager.createQuery("select o from ObjetoRisco o", ObjetoRisco.class).getResultList();
}
```

Na minha classe `Controller`, estou tendo muita dificuldade pra filtrar o valor máximo da coluna ID usando API Java 8.
O mais próximo que cheguei do resultado desejado foi desta maneira:

```
Optional<Integer> maxId = objetoRiscoDao.findAll().stream().map(ObjetoRisco::getId).max(Integer::compare);
modelAndView.addObject("maxId", maxId);
```

Mas quando chamo na minha JSP `${maxId}`, recebo como resposta `Optional[270]`.
De fato o 270 é o último Id, mas não estou conseguindo trazê-lo como inteiro para que eu possa manipulá-lo, tipo: `${maxId + 1}`.

Comment: @MauryDeveloper Não precisa adicionar **```java** nos blocos de código. Como a pergunta já tem a tag [java], o syntax highlight é aplicado automaticamente, sem precisar indicar a linguagem. Veja mais detalhes no FAQ: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/401803

Answer (score 4):

Basta "desenvelopar" o conteúdo do `Optional`:

```
Optional<Integer> maxId = objetoRiscoDao.findAll().stream().map(ObjetoRisco::getId).max(Integer::compare);
modelAndView.addObject("maxId", maxId.get());
```

Ou melhor:

```
Integer maxId = objetoRiscoDao.findAll().stream().map(Integer::new).max(Integer::compare).orElse(1); // Retorna valor padrão
```

Ou:

```
Integer maxId = objetoRiscoDao.findAll().stream().map(Integer::new).max(Integer::compare).orElseGet(() -> 1 + 2); // Retorna algum cálculo ou resultado de função
```

Ou ainda:

```
Integer maxId = objetoRiscoDao.findAll().stream().map(Integer::new).max(Integer::compare).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Não existe máximo")); // Lança exceção caso deva existir máximo
```

Comment: Opa...sua solução foi muito melhor que a minha... vou usá-la.
Muitíssimo obrigado!!

Comment: @Cristian Não é questão de "melhor". Esse é o jeito certo de trabalhar com `Optional`. O hashcode "funciona" por coincidência, já que a implementação atual dele é retornar o próprio número (mas nada impede que isso mude em versões futuras, pois é detalhe interno de implementação). Sem contar que o hashcode retorna zero se o valor não existir (lembre-se, é um `Optional`, o valor pode não existir). Já usar `get` e os métodos `orElse...` é o jeito certo de tratar o resultado

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver usando o recurso abaixo:

```
Integer max = maxId.hashCode();
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Faltou extrair o Integer contido no Optional:

```
modelAndView.addObject("maxId", maxId.get());
```

Contudo vale lembra que este Optional pode conter um `null` internamente, logo requer um tratamento ou check antes do extraí-lo.